# map inside pipe is ignored and http call is not triggered

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx, angular-services

I'm facing an issue  when I call a web service on an effect

I have created the effect here

```
$LoadSchedulingsByMission = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<any>(ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByDirection),
    mergeMap(action =>
      this.apiCallsService.getDirections(action.payload, '2016-04-18').pipe(
        map(trips => ({ type: ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByDirectionSuccess, payload: trips })),
        catchError(() => EMPTY)
      )
    )
  )
);
```

the `GetSchedulesByDirection` Action that take an array of strings

```
export class GetDirections implements Action {
  public readonly type = ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByDirection;
  constructor(public payload: string[]) {}
}
```

Then I call a http service that takes the array of string above.

```
getDirections(dataArrayToLoop: string[], date:string) {
  const groupByDirection:any={};
  dataArrayToLoop.map(elm=> {
    let dirUrl=`.....date=${date}&directions=${elm}`
    this.http.get<ISchedules>(dirUrl).pipe(map(dirData=>{
      groupByDirection[elm].push(dirData.data)
    }))
  })
  return of(groupByDirection);
}
```

Finally `Success` Action

```
export class GetDirectionsSuccess implements Action {
  public readonly type = ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByDirectionSuccess;
  constructor(public payload: ISchedules) {}
}
```

The reducers

```
case ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByDirection: {
  return {
    ...state,
  };
}
case ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByDirectionSuccess: {
  return {
    ...state,
    directions: action.payload
  };
}
```

The problem is that the http call is not triggered , I verified that the dataarray is not empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning `of(groupByDirection)` before the callback happens. You needd something like this:

```
getDirections(dataArrayToLoop: string[], date:string) {
  const groupByDirection = dataArrayToLoop.map(elm => {
    let dirUrl=`.....date=${date}&directions=${elm}`;

    return this.http.get<ISchedules>(dirUrl).pipe(
      map(dirData=> dirData.data),
    );
  })
  return combineLatest(groupByDirection);
}
```